# fetching,viewing and updating checkbox values stored in db

Tags: php, checkbox

i have a html form that has a hidden id and 20 checkboxes. checkboxes are used to select a service as available or not. the values are then stored as 0 or 1 each in their own column for each unique id.
code for inserting checkbox values is as follows:

```
$chkbox = array('antenatal', 'arvtherapy', 'basicemergencyobstericcare', 'bloodtransfusion', 'caesereansection', 'curativeinpatient', 'curativeoutpatient', 'familyplanning', 'vct', 'homebasedcare', 'immunization', 'imofci', 'radiology', 'ruralhealthtraining', 'tuberculosis', 'cardiology','physiotherapy', 'spinalinjury', 'dental', 'optical');

if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    $id= $_GET['id'];   
    $serviceno = $_POST['serviceno'];
    $values = array();
    foreach($chkbox as $selection )
    {     
        if (in_array($selection, $serviceno))
        { 
            $values[ $selection ] = 1;  
        }
        else
        { 
            $values[ $selection ] = 0;  
        }
    }
```

then insert as follows:

```
 $insert = "INSERT INTO hospitalservices (id,antenatal, arvtherapy,...,..." 
 VALUES ('$id',{$values['antenatal']}, {$values['arvtherapy']},...,...,....]})";
```

note for the above i have inserted 3 but in the code i've done so for all 20

question: how do i fetch the checkbox values from the database so that those that were checked are shown and those which were not checked still unchecked in html form, then consequently edit them.